# Android application to record reminders of what to talk about to specific people

Tags: android, reminders, contact-manager

There are many things you need to discuss with relatives, friends, family, co-workers, other people. These things gather, sometimes you want to ask multiple people the same question, other times you just have a lot of stuff you have to talk about with a person, but you always forget some and you end up calling the person, or hoping you won't forget next time.

I have been using [Google Keep](https://www.google.com/keep/) notes with checkboxes and a specific label for this purpose, but I do not like the workflow of it. I like to use Keep for stuff I want to *keep*.
My requirement is much more specific than a general keep purpose.

Using [Trello](https://trello.com/) for this is also overkill.
I need an app with functionality covering this very specific, but expandable use case.

Is there any app for this or anything at least closely resembling it? It would be nice if it made use of contact list too.

Use case:

1. Remember I need to talk about X to person Y.
2. In the app find a person from contact list or add it manually
3. A list of things to talk about pops up. You can add new topics to be covered. The level of detail is not important.
4. Time reminder for when you know you meet a person would be excellent, or if you have an event in calendar which you share with the person, it would be good to be reminded at the event. Also possibly place reminder, if that is characterisitc for a person, but this is not mandatory.
5. Check things out of the list.
6. You can alternatively add a topic with adding all the people to cover it with. This will distribute the topic among all the people.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. E.g. do you need it connected to the people's records/calls?

Comment: Okay, I will elaborate

Comment: I elaborated. I believe no more information should be required, it covers the functionatliy as I would expect it - I do not expect more, so I would not know what more you would like to hear

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if those are good matches, but with the details you've provided they might: I've thought of apps for [Calling Notes](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_917). Those not only let you make notes on the "ongoing call", but also let you put reminders for "when calling X, don't forget talking about Y" – which at least partly meets your requirements and might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I wanted, but most of them are, as name suggests trying to show stuff when I want to call with them, which was not intended and I wouldn't use it, actually it would bother me. I want to discuss these things when I am personally with them, otherwise it's usual for me to just straight away call them. I tried a few, I'll try some more but they all want to show something while calling, unfortunately

Comment: I was afraid of something like that (which is why I only mentioned them in a comment). Well, was worth a try, though, I hope. The perfect match I don't know, sorry – but good luck for your further search!